# python Compare two dataframe values and get distinct values from first dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes like below

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Server": ["Server1", "Server1","Server1","Server1","Server1"],
        "FileName": [
            "2020-05-01T18:18:00Z/Server1/file1",
            "2020-05-01T18:18:13Z/Server1/file2",
            "2020-05-01T18:20:47Z/Server1/file3",
            "2020-05-01T18:21:46Z/Server1/file4",
            "2020-05-01T18:24:43Z/Server1/file5",
        ],
    }
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Server": ["Server1", "Server1","Server1","Server1","Server1"],
        "FileName": [
            "2020-05-01T18:18:00Z/Server1/file1",
            "2020-05-01T18:18:13Z/Server1/file2",
            "2020-05-01T18:20:47Z/Server1/file3",
            "2020-05-01T18:33:08Z/Server1/file6",
            "2020-05-01T18:33:11Z/Server1/file7",
        ],
    }
)
```

df1:

```
                             FileName   Server
0  2020-05-01T18:18:00Z/Server1/file1  Server1
1  2020-05-01T18:18:13Z/Server1/file2  Server1
2  2020-05-01T18:20:47Z/Server1/file3  Server1
3  2020-05-01T18:21:46Z/Server1/file4  Server1
4  2020-05-01T18:24:43Z/Server1/file5  Server1
```

df2:

```
                             FileName   Server
0  2020-05-01T18:18:00Z/Server1/file1  Server1
1  2020-05-01T18:18:13Z/Server1/file2  Server1
2  2020-05-01T18:20:47Z/Server1/file3  Server1
3  2020-05-01T18:33:08Z/Server1/file6  Server1
4  2020-05-01T18:33:11Z/Server1/file7  Server1
```

I want Files from df1 which are not in df2. Column Server is insignificant here. I want below dataframe

```
                             FileName   Server
0  2020-05-01T18:21:46Z/Server1/file4  Server1
1  2020-05-01T18:24:43Z/Server1/file5  Server1
```

I have achieved this by looping through each value. Is there any small and fast way to do this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    flag = 0
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row1['FileName'] == row2['FileName']:
            flag = 1
    if flag == 0:
        df = df.append({'Server': row1['Server'], 'FileName': row1['FileName']}, ignore_index=True)
print df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use isin method

```
df1[~df1['FileName'].isin(df2['FileName'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about how efficient this would be, but you can use this 1 liner code instead of use loop to iterate your dataframes.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer' ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only'])
del result["_merge"] #You can keep this _merge column

print(result)
```

#### output

```
    Server                            FileName
3  Server1  2020-05-01T18:21:46Z/Server1/file4
4  Server1  2020-05-01T18:24:43Z/Server1/file5
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
df1[df1['FileName'] != df2['FileName']].reset_index(drop=True)
```